# JavaScript parsing JSON from server

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to parse a JSON object received from my server. This is my server's response:

```
[
  {
    "idPais": "1",
    "nombre": "España"
  },
  {
    "idPais": "2",
    "nombre": "Grecia"
  },
  {
    "idPais": "3",
    "nombre": "Holanda"
  },
  {
    "idPais": "4",
    "nombre": "Finlandia"
  },
  {
    "idPais": "5",
    "nombre": "Suiza"
  }
]
```

In my script, I tried to get the objects with one array, but `resp` is always `undefined`.

```
function loadCountries(cont) { // Listado de paises con contenidos
  var i = 0;
  var method = 'GET';
  var path = appConstants.requestCountriesURL(cont);
  console.log(path);
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();   
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    alert('Status es: ' + xhr.status + 'State es: ' + xhr.readyState);
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      alert('Recogiendo respuesta...');
      resp = xhr.responseText;
    }
  }
  xhr.open(method, path, false); // Creamos la peticion
  resp = xhr.send(); // Guardamos la respuesta
  if(resp == false || resp == undefined) {
    alert('La lista de paises no se pudo obtener');
    return resp;
  } else {
    alert('La lista de paises se obtuvo correctamente');
    console.log(resp);
    var listaPaises = JSON.parse(resp);
    return listaPaises;
  }
}
```

The error shown is the following:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
```

**Edit with solution 1:**

```
function checkCountries(i){
    alert('oncheckCountries');
    var answer=$('input[name^="radio-choice"]:checked').val();
    alert('val es: '+ answer);
    $('#divPaises').css('display','block');
    getCountries(answer);

}
function getCountries(continente){
    alert('on getCountries');
    loadCountries(continente);
}
function loadCountries(cont){ //Listado de paises con contenidos
    var i = 0;
    var method = 'GET';
    var path = appConstants.requestCountriesURL(cont);
    console.log (path);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        alert('Status es: '+xhr.status+'State es: '+xhr.readyState);
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
            alert('Recogiendo respuesta...');
            resp = xhr.responseText;
            if(resp == false || resp == undefined){
                alert('La lista de paises no se pudo obtener');
                return resp;
            }
            else{
                    alert('La lista de paises se obtuvo correctamente');
                    console.log(resp);
                    var listaPaises = JSON.parse(resp);
                    console.log(listaPaises[0]);
                    var size = Object.keys(listaPaises).length;
                    var select = document.createElement('select');
                    alert('Select creado');
                    select.name = 'selectPais';
                    select.id = 'selectPais';
                    for(i=0;i<size ;i++){
                            var option = document.createElement('option');
                            option.id = listaPaises[i].idPais;
                            option.value = listaPaises[i].nombre;
                            option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(listaPaises[i].nombre));
                            alert(option.getAttribute('value'));
                            select.appendChild(option);
                            }
                    document.getElementById('divPaises').appendChild(select);
                }
        }
    }
    xhr.open(method, path, true); //Creamos la peticion
    resp = xhr.send(); // Guardamos la respuesta    
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Shouldn't you check the `resp` after you get the response back? Right now you are checking its even before the server has sent you response back ..

Comment: totally not duplicated of that post.

Comment: You are assign in the wrong place a value to `resp`. I think that you don't need this line `resp = xhr.send();` , you are getting the answer here `resp = xhr.responseText;`

Comment: ^ Since you're making it synchronous you can `resp = xhr.responseText;` right after `xhr.send();` as Rafael suggested. But I'd highly recommend to make it async to avoid blocking the entire page while waiting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue here is that you are using the result of `xhr.send()` as the response, when it's not. If you want to parse the response you have to do it in the `onreadystatechange` listener, using `xhr.responseText`, like this:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    alert('Status es: '+xhr.status+'State es: '+xhr.readyState);
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
        alert('Recogiendo respuesta...');
        resp = xhr.responseText;

        if(resp == false || resp == undefined){
            alert('La lista de paises no se pudo obtener');
        } else {
            alert('La lista de paises se obtuvo correctamente');
            console.log(resp);
            var listaPaises = JSON.parse(resp);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you cannot return the response since that the request is asynchronous, so you have to either do everything inside your function, or use a callback function, like this:

```
function loadCountries(cont, callback) { // use a callback
    var i = 0;
    var method = 'GET';
    var path = appConstants.requestCountriesURL(cont);
    console.log (path);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        alert('Status es: '+xhr.status+'State es: '+xhr.readyState);
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
            alert('Recogiendo respuesta...');
            resp = xhr.responseText;

            if(resp == false || resp == undefined){
                alert('La lista de paises no se pudo obtener');
                callback(resp);
            } else {
                alert('La lista de paises se obtuvo correctamente');
                console.log(resp);
                var listaPaises = JSON.parse(resp);
                callback(listaPaises);
            }
        }
    }

    xhr.open(method, path, false);
    xhr.send();
}


// Create a callback
function myCallback(data) {
    // Do what you want with the data...
}

// Call the function like this...
function loadCountries(myCont, myCallback);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In this case my request is syncronous, why can not i "return" values?

Comment: @Asier No, your request is asyncronous! You are using false on the last parameter of xhr.open(), so it's asynchronous.

Comment: I think no, true is async, false is sync. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests

Comment: @Asier ok you're right, so you should put true in your request, which is better.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but if i put True, the code hops and i have not time to get data before return false. Wait a moment, im trying your answer.

Comment: I solved it. I will post the answer. I do all without callback function at the moment but i will put the code on it. I already tried it but when i try to get listaPaises array on another array in the callback function, it fails and destiny array stay "undefined".

Answer (score 1):

It is an asynchronous call and you are trying to handle it as a synchronous one.

```
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    alert('Status es: ' + xhr.status + 'State es: ' + xhr.readyState);
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      alert('Recogiendo respuesta...');
      resp = xhr.responseText;
      //Do your stuff with resp here
    }
  }
  xhr.open(method, path, false); // Creamos la peticion
  xhr.send(); //Send will not return anything
```

Check here if you want more examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Its correct but i read first another. Thank you!